# How to return wlst python value to shell

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, wlst

I am launching a wlst python script like this :

cmd file :

```
call /oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.cmd myWlstScript.py
PAUSE
```

The python script is checking if a datasource is up :

```
connect('XXXX','XXXX','t3://XXXX.local:XXXX')
serverRuntime()
dsMBeans = cmo.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
#Do stuff to check datasource state
```

How can i return a value from the wlst python script to the cmd file ? (or shell)

Comment: You can use `sys.exit(val)` if val is an int. Otherwise you'll need to write to std__ and use pipes, write to a well-known file name, or use a storage system like e.g. redis.

Comment: @thebjorn using sys.exit(val). How can i retreive and use the val in the cmd/shell file ?

Comment: Look in the `ERRORLEVEL` (http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) or `%ERRORLEVEL%` depending on what you need it for (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a value from the wlst python script to the cmd file in my simple case, i did the following :

python wlst

```
exit(exitcode=3)
```

cmd

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 echo it worked
```